# Importing a text file into Excel or Access using Java

Tags: java, excel, ms-access, text

New guy here.

I am creating a network mapping application for final year project. I am looking to import a text file containing result from "SHOW IP OSPF DATABASE" command carried out on my DR (to give whole view of network) I need to get my text file into excel or access using Java.

I am able to read the file into java but I am not sure how to export this text file into either excel or access.

Any help would be much appreciated!

If you need any more explaining just let me know.

Thanks

Edit: My programming understanding is very basic

Comment: Open the file, and find out what the delimiter is. Then use that delimiter to parse the file. If you post some of the file, I can help you with that.

Comment: Sorry looks like I read your question wrong. Excel can handle tab, or comma delimiters right out of the box. I suggest you use those. Excel will recognize this when you open the file and ask which to use. Save the file with an xls extension

Comment: Thanks for replies, I think I would prefer to use Access. For this, would I be right in thinking I need to use JDBC?

Comment: Yes, and that is probably the cleanest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

it is very friendly and easy to use library